# If $A$ is a compact operator then $e^A$ is also compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have a simple question:

Let $A \in L(X)$ be a bounded linear operator on the normed space $X$.

It is not too difficult to see that the exponential operator $e^A = \sum_{\substack{k = 0}}^{\infty} \frac{A^k}{k!}$ is linear and bounded by using the extended Triangle Inequality.

And that will give us $||e^A|| \leq e^{||A||}$, as well.

Now the question is to show that if $A$ is compact then $e^A$ is also compact?

My idea is to look at $e^A$ as a composition of the identity function $Id: K(X) \rightarrow K(X)$ which takes $A(t) \in K(X)$ to $A(t)$ for all $t \in X$; with the exponential function $exp: L(X) \rightarrow L(X) $ that takes $x(t)$ to $e^{x(t)} = \sum_{\substack{k = 0}}^{\infty} \frac{{x(t)}^k}{k!}$. And as $exp$ is continuous and bounded and $Id$ a compact operator, so $exp(Id): K(x) \rightarrow K(x)$ will be a compact operator?

Please correct me if I am wrong and so far from being right?

Thanks!

Comment: It generally isn't, $e^0 = I$ is only compact if the space is finite-dimensional.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! Why in general is not compact? Is it provable?

Comment: @DanielFischer And why my idea for to use the composition will not work?

Comment: Note: $Id$ is not a compact operator on the space $K(X)$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks! Yes, now I got that I had to mention $X$ is an infinite dimensional space. But there is just I cannot understand why invertibilty which has been mentioned in the answer, gives us not compactness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$e^A$ is always invertible, so never compact on an infinite-dimensional Banach space.  What is true is that $e^A - I$ is compact if $A$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks! But can you please explain that why invertiblity implies not compactness? And in what conditions?

Comment: And why my idea for to use the composition will not work? Thanks!

Comment: @user509540 : The assumption would be that you're working in an infinite-dimensional space; in that context an invertible is never compact. It's reasonable to assume $X$ is infinite-dimensional; otherwise all the linear operators are compact.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks! But why invertibility in an infinite dimensional space will give us not compactness? What it has to do with compactness?

Comment: @user509540  : Two facts: 1. If $A$ is invertible, then $m\|x\| \le \|Ax\| \le M\|x\|$ for all $x$ and non-zero constants $m,M$. 2. The unit sphere in an infinite-dimensional space normed space is not compact.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Many thanks!

Comment: The compact operators form an ideal in the bounded linear operators.  If $A$ was invertible and compact, $I = A A^{-1}$ would be compact.